# Compiling multiple .Net assemblies with mono in JScript (not C#)?

Tags: mono, unity-game-engine, .net-assembly, jscript

does anyone know how I could make a number of separate assemblies out of my 50+ Unity3D scripts? My scripts are all written in JScript.Net and compiled by Unity using relatively old Mono compiler tools (v2.0 I believe).

Comment: So, you want to split the contents of Assembly-UnityScript.dll into separate assemblies?

Comment: Yes indeed. With only 1 dll, compilation time has gone higher and higher. Besides, having explicit dependencies will improve code readability if nothing else.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706377/how-do-you-extract-classes-source-code-from-a-dll-file might help. Have you tried just renaming Assembly-UnityScript.dll, moving it into your plugins folder, and deleting the source files? (Don't try w/o backups!!)