# Is there any way to convert .dll file to .cs files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Is there any way to convert .dll file to .cs files?
I am searching for any tool or online website what can convert .dll file into .cs files.
If any one have any info please inform 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: DLL files don't contain their source code. The best you can do is use a decompiler. Assuming you have the licence to do so, of course.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706377/how-do-you-extract-classes-source-code-from-a-dll-file

Comment: Read [ask] and share your research.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, in general, that's not possible (in any compiled language).

You can decompile binaries for .NET into CIL ([Common Intermediate Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)), which is an object-oriented assembly language. Various .NET languages (C#, F#, Visual Basic, etc.) are compiled into the bytecode, which is then being executed by the .NET virtual machine rather than by the processor.

Thanks to that the .NET bytecode is platform independent, it can be executed on any platform for which the .NET virtual machine exists without the recompilation.

You can decompile the .NET binaries into CIL using for example these free decompilers:

- [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net) (standalone or as a [Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SharpDevelopTeam.ILSpy))
- JetBrains' [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)
- Telerik's [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)

dotPeek has a feature to decompile any .NET binary into *equivalent* C# code, but it's not same as the original C# code.

Comment: Hi thanks man. dotPeek is working nice for me.

Comment: ILSpy does not work properly, I does not recover namespace blocks.
Telerik worked well.

Comment: ILSpy works for me. I've added the [VS Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SharpDevelopTeam.ILSpy). It's simple and free

Answer (score 0):

You can use this http://ilspy.net/, it is a really good tool will convert you dll to .cs files

Answer (score 0):

You can try anyone of the third party decompilation tool to get your code from dll.

One of the most recognized: .[Net reflector tool](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/).

NOTE: You can convert it only to [MSIL (Intermediate Language)](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/il/article.php/c4635/MSIL-Tutorial.htm):