# Convert dll file to source code

Tags: c, dll

Half year ago I reinstalled operation system and unfortunately deleted source code which I converted to dll, and now I have only dll file and don't know how to convert it to source code, I tried to use reflector but it didn't help? Can anyone help me please?

**UPD**

*is not a .NET module.* my main problem is here, when I trying to usr .Net reflector, and this error message when I add my dll to my programm 1C

and reflector in my case doesn't work

**system.type system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.gettypefromclsid**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decompile a .dll file created in VS.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503943/how-to-decompile-a-dll-file-created-in-vs-net)   ||  [Is there any way to convert .dll file to .cs files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039254/is-there-any-way-to-convert-dll-file-to-cs-files)

Comment: C or C#? Forget it for C. For c# it's possible, although variable names and/or function names will be gone, google "c# decompiler". _"but it didn't help"_. How?

Comment: `git checkout` ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz code was written in the C

Comment: If your code was written in C, forget decompiling and count your losses. You need to rewrite your code. Reflector can only decompile c# code.

Answer (score 3):

It's tough to get back your original source code from the DLL. You can try some decompiler tools to see if it works

https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: @Scovetta on C language

Comment: Best you can get back to is assembly. There are some decompilers that claim to get back to C but I’ve never seen one produce anything legible. It’s been a while though. Maybe give this a shot: https://derevenets.com

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is like separating the ingredients of a backed cake. You can separate some components, but not in the original quality. The DLL is not your source code - it's a product of your source code. Like the cake. Sorry.