# I want to get codebehind from published .net webforms project

Tags: c#, .net, iis, webforms, code-behind

I accidentally formatted the disk that contains my .net webforms project. I only have published one. Now I want to get c# codes from published project. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, unless you have not used any confuscator. You can use [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) for example.

Comment: You can also refer the below URL
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706377/how-do-you-extract-classes-source-code-from-a-dll-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the exact code, but you can use some softwares that 'decompile' the dll. I call this reverse engineering.

Personally I use **ILSPy**, heres ILSPy GitHub Repository: https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy

Hope this works for you! Thx